# Angular2: Configuration 'name' conflicts with existing route 'name'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have some components of which one with dynamic routes.

the dynamic routes are added as,

```
let config = [];
for(let i = 0; i < this.pages.length; i++) {
  config.push({
    path: this.pages[i].slug, 
    name : this.pages[i].name, 
    component: AnotherComponent,
  });
}
router.config(config);
```

whenever the component with dynamic route is loaded more than once, the routes are configured again and that results in configuration conflict.

Here's the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UKOfQR1abPL90h3VH7bp?p=preview), The dynamic routes are loaded with the link `users`, clicking again on `users` after navigating away from user logs the below shown error to the console.
[image]

How do I fix it? Thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the route exists before adding it

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.pages.length; i++) {
  if(!router.registry.hasRoute(this.pages[i].name, UsersComponent)) {
    config.push({
      path: this.pages[i].slug, 
      name : this.pages[i].name, 
      component: PersonComponent,
      data : {
        name : this.pages[i].name,
        slug : this.pages[i].slug
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ya8M0spq5ayOvWAeOtYh?p=preview)