# Angular2 check if router has already been configured

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm working on an **Angular2** (currently we're on the beta-17 version) application, and I have some nested routing that is configured. Everything seems to be working as expected except one interesting issue.

After a while simply navigating betwixt the various child routes the `router` instance will lose its routes that had been configured. At the top-level we have two routes that just so happen to be pointing to the same `component` just for *testing / proof of concept*. The `component` **TypeScript** looks like this:

```
// imports and decorators omitted for brevity...

export class HostNavAndBodyComponent implements OnInit {
    userRoutes = UserRoutes.empty;

    constructor(private router: Router, private routeService: RouteService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.userRoutes) {
            return;
        }

        this.routeService
            .getRoutes(userRoutes => {
                this.userRoutes = userRoutes;
                try {
                    this.router
                        .config(
                            this.userRoutes
                                .routes
                                .map((value, _, __) => value.definition));
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
           });
    }
}
```

I added the line to check for the `this.userRoutes` to prevent errant attempts to configure the router mistakenly multiple times. It works for a while, but then all of a sudden the underlying router losing its configured routes and since we do not re-enter -- there are no routes. Holy  batman!

My question, is there a way to check if a `router` has already been configured?

Comment: You don't have `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` on multiple components? Never heard of such an issue. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Are there any plunker templates to start from?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/8Tv6uf?p=info

Comment: I was struggling to get the plunker to work at all. I figured it out though, as you called attention to the `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` was at the global scope, therefore all `router` instances where actually the same instance -- as such it was a singleton and attempts to invoke `router.config` would error.

Comment: Angular creates a tree of routers by itself. If you intervene with that, you won't come far. `router.config` should still work but not on subsequent loads of the same routes if the component was already loaded.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114571/angular2-configuration-name-conflicts-with-existing-route-name/36114986#36114986