# Angular2 routing, parent child -- route component vs view component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm working on an **Angular2** application, currently we're on beta-17 since the release candidate no longer supported bundling and broke everything (that's another story).

I understand that the relationship between parent and child routes are expected to be that the child must be a "routing component" if it wants to have routes. That makes sense, right -- but what if I want to have a parent "routing component", that has a child "view component" which acts as a parent to a child "routing component"?

```
.
├── app.component // Has two child routes, both are "view components"
     ├── plan.component
     └── design.component // View component, route "/design/:id/..."
         ├── header.component
         ├── nav-and-body.component // Routing component
         └── footer.component
```

I have a top-level app that has two routes, the `/plan/:id/...` and `/design/:id/...` routes. As you can see I have a desire that these will serve as parents to other "routing components". Imagine we're in the "design" route, and we attempt to navigate to a child route defined in the `NavAndBodyComponent` it doesn't work, nor does it throw an error.

I believe this is due to the fact that I have a parent "routing component", that has a child "view component", which has a nested "routing component" - how can I fix this without changing this hierarchy?

The view components load as expected:

URL: `localhost:5000/design/10`

But when I attempt navigation to the nested child route the URL changes to

URL: `localhost:5000/model`

I want (and expected):

URL: `localhost:5000/design/10/model`

**Update**

Here is a very detailed <kbd>[`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/wyMnt4?p=preview)</kbd>!

Comment: Can you create a Plunker. I find it pretty hard to understand what you try to accomplish. If I understand the question then I guess having an intermediate component with just one route with path `/...` and `useAsDefault: true` and a `<router-outlet>` should do what you want.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I cannot seem to get a plunker working at all with beta.17 and routing. Any good starting points for angular2 beta.17 plunker?

Comment: Just post the link to the plunker you have. I'll have a look and try to make it work.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer https://plnkr.co/edit/JK4HhQ?p=preview

Comment: The plunker is working now. Please check if this is what you want https://plnkr.co/edit/LRQdTo?p=info

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This is a closer representation of how we're doing it, our routes come from a `Web API` call and we have to load them via the `AsyncRoute` dynamically at runtime. https://plnkr.co/edit/5XL3zK?p=preview

Comment: Seems to work fine, except when you add the `router.config` the 2nd time in `Intermediate` it throws. You might need to find a way to check if that route is already registered and than skip that step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111558/discussion-between-david-pine-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer available to check out my latest plunker update https://plnkr.co/edit/wyMnt4?p=preview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by adding `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` on a component other than the root component.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/F4ksfF?p=preview)

How to prevent adding dynamically added routes each time a route is activated see [Angular2: Configuration 'name' conflicts with existing route 'name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114571/angular2-configuration-name-conflicts-with-existing-route-name/36114986#36114986)

Comment: Now the `useAsDefault` is not honored, I have to manually select "Model" -- how can I fix that too?

Comment: Actually I don't know. I haven't used this much myself. It's also different in the new router, therefore I don't want to spend much time investigating in the old router anymore. (The new router doesn't have `useAsDefault` yet). I'm not sure there is a way to make `useAsDefault` work with dynamically configured routes. Maybe you can add the default route statically?